# Mongodump while writing

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

Is it safe to run `mongodump` against running server with many writes per second? Is it possible to get corrupted dump doing in this way?

From [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/):

> Use `--oplog` to capture incoming write operations during the mongodump operation to ensure that the backups reflect a consistent data state.

Does it mean that no matter how many writes in database dump will be consistent?

If I ran `mongodump --oplog` at 1AM and it finished at 2AM then I run `mongorestore --oplogReplay` what state will I get?

From [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#bin.mongodump):

> However, the use of `mongodump` and `mongorestore` as a backup strategy can be problematic for sharded clusters and replica sets.

but why? I had replica set of 1 primary and 2 secondary. What the problem to run `mongodump` against one of secondary? It should same as primary (except replication lag difference).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#bin.mongodump) are quite clear about it:

> `--oplog`
>
> Creates a file named `oplog.bson` as part of the mongodump output. The `oplog.bson` file, located in the top level of the output directory, contains oplog entries that occur during the mongodump operation. This file provides an effective point-in-time snapshot of the state of a mongod instance. To restore to a specific point-in-time backup, use the output created with this option in conjunction with `mongorestore --oplogReplay`.
>
> Without `--oplog`, if there are write operations during the dump operation, the dump will not reflect a single moment in time. Changes made to the database during the update process can affect the output of the backup.
>
> `--oplog` has no effect when running mongodump against a mongos instance to dump the entire contents of a sharded cluster. However, you can use `--oplog` to dump individual shards.

Without `--oplog` you still get a valid dump, just a bit inconsistent - some of the writes done between 1 AM and 2 AM will be missing.

With `--oplog` you have the oplog file captured at 2 AM. The dump remains inconsistent, and replaying the oplog on restore fixes this issue.

The problems dumping the sharded clusters deserve a [dedicated page in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-sharded-cluster-with-database-dumps/). Essentially because of complexity to synchronise backups of all nodes:

> To create backups of a sharded cluster, you will **stop the cluster balancer, take a backup of the config database, and then take backups of each shard in the cluster** using mongodump to capture the backup data. To capture a more exact moment-in-time snapshot of the system, you will need to stop all application writes before taking the filesystem snapshots; otherwise the snapshot will only approximate a moment in time.

There are no problems to dump replica set.